# Destroy the element that called the onKeyDown event

Tags: freepascal

I'm currently working with Free Pascal and I'm having issues dealing with an onKeyDown event. Thing is, whenever i try to use the onKeyDown event to destroy (ex: element.Free) elements (including the one that called the event) I'm getting a SIGSEV exception. I've tried changing the element focus before excuting the "Free" process, but to no avail.

Is there a way to smoothly remove (Free) elements without getting a "SIGSEV" exception? I've been succesful in excuting the same method using a button, but right now Im required to set it to work with onKeyDown events, and so one of the elements that needs to be set "Free" happens to have focus at the moment the onKeyDown event is triggered.

Hope this is clear, let me know if you need somethingelse,

Oscar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cause:

As I understand you are trying something like

```
procedure TElement.OnKeyPress(...);
begin
  Free;
end;
```

There are several answers here why you must not to destroy object inside its event handler. In few words: the object may want to doing something after calling your event handler and if it already destroyed by you - you will have SIGSEGV in this case.

Solution:

You have to postpone destroy the object. There are several cases: using PostMessage, using Application.QueueAsyncCall and so on.

There is simple example:

```
type
    TForm1 = class(TForm)
        Button1: TButton;
        procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    private
        procedure FreeButton(Data: PtrInt);
    public
    end;

var
    Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.lfm}

{ TForm1 }

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
    Application.QueueAsyncCall(@FreeButton, PtrInt(Button1));
end;

procedure TForm1.FreeButton(Data: PtrInt);
begin
    TButton(Data).Free;
end;
```

[Read more about Application.QueueAsyncCall.](http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/Asynchronous_Calls)

Comment: You, sir, are a life saver! This is exactly what I assumed was happening, but didn't know how to properly approach it. Funny how easy it actually was. Thanks again @Abelisto! :D :D